# Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent les acceptions de « cartonner » qui ne paraissent pas liées au carton ?

Tags: étymologie

Comment les acceptions 1, 2 (qui évidemment concernent le carton) ont-elles glissé à celles-ci ci-dessus qui ne sont pas manifestement liées au carton ?  [Wiktionnaire :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cartonner#%C3%89tymologie)

> 3. *([Familier](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#F))* [Attaquer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/attaquer) ou [critiquer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/critiquer) [vigoureusement](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigoureusement).
> 4. *([Argot](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#A))* [Posséder](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poss%C3%A9der) sexuellement.
> 5. _([Intransitif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#I))__([Familier](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#F))_ Avoir du [succès](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/succ%C3%A8s), l’[emporter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/emporter) [haut la main](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/haut_la_main), [faire un carton](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_un_carton#fr).
> 6. *([Intransitif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#I))* *([Populaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#P))* Être en [danger](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/danger), [exposé](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/expos%C3%A9), etc.
> 7. *([Intransitif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#I))* *([Populaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Glossaire_grammatical#P))* Entrer en [collision](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/collision), avoir un accident de voiture.

Answer (score 3):

Toutes ces acceptions sont indirectement liées au carton, plus précisément au carré de carton que l'on trouve dans un stand de tir à la fête foraine et sur lequel est imprimée la cible .

[image]

L'idée principale commune est celle de choc, de violence, de mettre « en plein dans le mille ».